# how to retrieve character values from table in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I insert data in mysql database like as-

```
create table details(loginid varchar(55),interser1 char,interser2 char,interser3 char);
insert into details  values("1",'y','n','y');
```

when i am retriving in jsp-

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from interest where loginid='1'");
String interest1=rs.getString(2);//but at index-2 value is character.
String interest2=rs.getString(3);
String interest3=rs.getString(4);
```

this is giving me Error-

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/more_value_in_param] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /display.jsp at line 19

16: Connection con=CommonUtil.getConnection();
17: Statement st=con.createStatement();
18: ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from interest where loginid='1'");
19: String interest1=rs.getString(2);
20: String interest2=rs.getString(3);
21: String interest3=rs.getString(4);
22: ResultSet rs1=st.executeQuery("select * from details where loginid='1'");


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5650)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570)
    at org.apache.jsp.display_jsp._jspService(display_jsp.java:84)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

how to retrieve character values from table in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to call `rs.next()` to ensure there is result first before retrieving any result. So you will need to have:

```
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from interest where loginid='1'");
while (rs.next()) {
   String interest1=rs.getString(2);
   String interest2=rs.getString(3);
   String interest3=rs.getString(4);
}
```

For you question, you can get the character by calling `rs.getString(2).charAt(0)`. By the way, if possible, please try to have this logic in your controller or action, not in JSP.

Comment: This is correct I think - what you are doing is basically calling all the results from the table (st.executeQuery) and saving them to rs. So basically you have a copy of the table. Use rs.next() to get the next row of the table (or in your case the first row).

Comment: in case `ResultSet` have a single record,than still we have to call `rs.next()`?